# Open multiple programs with Cmd + Tab (Mac)

Tags: ios, macos, react-native

So developing in RN, I want to have VSCode + the mobile device open by pressing Cmd + Tab (or another command), and then close (or swap) with that same command. So instead of a single tab opening at once, I have multiple open.

Seems simple enough, but how do I go about this? Thanks! On a Mac Seirra.